# Populate Select based on another Select

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to populate a Select Box based in the choice of the first Select Box, but I'm having some troubles doing it. Simply nothing happens.

What I have until now (this is on my footer):

```
<script src="./plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select.category").change(function(){
    var selectedCategory = $(".category option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../inc/get_subcat.php",
        data: { category : selectedCategory } 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#subcategory").html(data);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

The page with the div is located at /pages/file.php:

```
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">SubCategory</label>
     <div id="subcategory"> </div>
 </div>                                      </div>
```

The file that does the query is in another folder (inc/get_subcat.php):

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['category'])){
$cat = validar($_POST['category']);

$query = "SELECT id, subcategory FROM subcategories WHERE catid = ?";
#Prepare stmt or reports errors
($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) or trigger_error($mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
#Execute stmt or reports errors
$stmt->bind_param("i", $cat);
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
#Save data or reports errors
($stmt_result = $stmt->get_result()) or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
#Check if are rows in query
if ($stmt_result->num_rows>0) {
    echo "<select class='form-control' id='subcategory' name='subcategory'>";
    # Save in $row_data[] all columns of query
    while($row_data = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    # Action to do
        echo "<option value='$row_data[id]'>$row_data[category]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

There is someone that could help me trying to fix this error? Can't fix despite trying for some hours.

Thanks!

Edit:
This is the HTML code with all Select Box:

```
                                            <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                                                    <select class='form-control' id='category' name='category'><option value='1'>Categoria 1</option><option value='2'>Categoria 2</option></select>                                                    </div>                                          

                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6" id="subcategory">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Does your `$_POST` URL work? When you go to it, or test it with Postman, does it load anything? Does the AJAX request process? Using your browser tools, check to ensure that the request is successfully processing so the location of the issue can be identified.

Comment: what does this method do `validar()`? and what does error reporting throw back?

Comment: I don't have any error reported. The "validar" just espace strings and so on to avoid SQL Injection. It seems that the script is not calling. I don't get any error. If I go to the page "get_subcat" and define a value for $cat it drops the right values.

Comment: what does the web inspector network pane show?

Comment: It only shows the files that are loaded with the load page. In this case all CSS and JS (including jquery). If I change the first select box, nothing happens. My first select box code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML you have`<select class='form-control'`...etc

So the `<select>` has a class "form-control" only.

But your selector is `$("select.category").change`...etc. which means it's looking for a select with "category" in the class attribute (the dot `.` in the selector signifies a class). Such an element doesn't exist, hence why nothing happens.

Perhaps you meant to use the ID (in which case `$("#category").change`...etc)? Either that or you need to write `<select class='form-control category'`...etc before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem in your array data or query. So please check it first. 
I post here working example of depending drop down may be this will help you.

PHP code

```
$sub_category // Your array of Subcategory;
if ($sub_category) {
            echo '<option value="">Sub Category</option>';
            foreach ($sub_category as $sub_category) {
                $selected = '';
                if($sub_category['sub_category_id'] == $data['product']['sub_category_id'])
                {
                    $selected = 'selected';
                }
                echo '<option value="' . $sub_category['sub_category_id'] . '" '.$selected.'>' . $sub_category['sub_category'] . '</option>';
            }

        }
```

JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   loadSubCategory();

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(document).on('change', '.category_id', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            loadSubCategory();
        });

    });

    function loadSubCategory()
    {
           var category_id = $(".category_id option:selected").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Your Path Of server Function',
                type: 'post',
                data: {category_id: category_id, product_id : "<?= $product['product_id']?>" },
                cache: false,
                success: function (resp) {
                    if(resp)
                    {
                        $('.sub_category_id').html(resp);
                    } else {
                        $('.sub_category_id').html('<option value="">Sub Category</option>');
                    }

                }
            })
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <b>Product Category </b> 
                        <select class="form-control category_id" id="category_id" name="category_id">
                            <option>Category</option>
                        <?php 

                            <option value="<?= $value['category_id'] ?>"  <?=$selected ?> ><?= $value['category'] ?></option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Category End -->
                     <!-- Sub Category Start -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <b>Product Sub Category </b> 
                        <select class="form-control sub_category_id" name="sub_category_id">
                            <option value="">Sub Category</option>
                <option value="">Sub Category</option>
                 <option value="20">Books Stationery</option>
                                  <option value="21">Gaming and Accessories</option>
                                  <option value="22">Music Musical Instruments</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
```